# Loading Multiple Comments Pages via Ajax?

Tags: pages, ajax, comments

I have been searching Google and still haven't found any great ideas for making comments pages load via Ajax. After searching SE I found [this older thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64590/ajax-comments-not-working)
 from just a few months ago which provides a solution, but it seems to focus on submitted comments. Not loading the pages dynamically which requires a different type of query.

Similarly I am wondering if this would even be the proper solution? Wordpress has a seemingly instinctive way to implement certain functions, especially Ajax. So I am hoping to follow the most proper route for typical WP installs.

Happy to answer further questions. Thanks in advance for any help!